Docx4j not wrapping text in table cell when docx is converted to PDF
I am using DocX4j version 11.4.11 to convert docx file to PDF.
My word document has tables with words that are long and do not have any space.
The word document wraps such words to multiple lines. But when i convert the same docx file to PDF,
the word wrap does not happen and the text overlaps into the next table cell.
Word Document

The converted PDF is as below
PDF

I have data which have long words with no space.
So, i need docx4j to wrap such words.
I cannot modify the data to add characters like space or hyphens.
